# I want make an app that wants a pass when users want to unistall it

Tags: android

I want to make an app that when a user want to unistall it , he/she enters a pass for unistalling it.
I am very new in the android field.

Comment: You got my approval, you can proceed.

Comment: There are lots of things to learn about asking good questions but the first and most important one is to, err, ask a question!

Answer (score 1):

OK, here you go :

1. Go here http://source.android.com/source/building.html and download android OS source code.
2. Remove google play store from the system
3. Hack your own store and uninstall mechanism
4. Package the OS

Now you have your custom uninstall procedure, good luck!